# flex 4 center element in a group

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

I am playing around with flex 4 GUI with a simple alignment but couldnt figure out why.

I have button1, button2, and a text field. I want to align them horizontally, and center vertically for the text. 
For the following code, i see the following output.

```
_______   ______
|bt1   | |bt2   |   text1
|______| |______|
```

my question is;
 1) why with the properties i sent on btn 1 verticalCenter="10" and btn2 verticalCenter="-10" they are still aligned? shouldnt i see one is up and the one is donw?
2 ) why my text1 is aligned top, even though i set it to verticalCenter=0, i tried it with or without in a group.

Thanks guys

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955"
    minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:Group minWidth="100">
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:Button label="myButton" click="" horizontalCenter="0"
            verticalCenter="10"/>
        <s:Button label="myButton" click="" verticalCenter="-10"/>
        <s:Group verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">
            <s:Label text="hello" color="#FFFF" verticalCenter="0"
                textAlign="center" />
        </s:Group>

    </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be helpful for others to understand why this occurs, as it is a common problem.

When you use a `HorizontalLayout` or `VerticalLayout` some properties you set on the "layout objects" are not used. This occurs because these properties do not really work or make sense in a vertical/horizontal layout.

Layout properties that are ignored by vertical/horizontal layouts:

- `x` and `y` coordinates
- `horizontalCenter` and `verticalCenter`
- `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` contstraints

The above properties will work for the default `BasicLayout` class.

As indicated in the answer by @Mahesh Parate, the vertical/horizontal layouts do allow for content to be centered by using the `horizontalAlign` and `verticalAlign` properties.

Answer (score 1):

Below code may help you: - add  verticalAlign="middle" in HorizontalLayout this will solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955"
               minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            protected function onClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Group minWidth="100" >
        <s:layout>
            <s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle"/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:Button label="myButton" click="onClickHandler(event)" horizontalCenter="0"
                  verticalCenter="10"/>
        <s:Button label="myButton" click="onClickHandler(event)" verticalCenter="-10"/>
        <s:Group verticalCenter="0" horizontalCenter="0">
            <s:Label text="hello" color="#FFFF" verticalCenter="0"
                     textAlign="center" />
        </s:Group>

    </s:Group>
</s:Application>
```